# netsh winsock reset - What does it do and why did my wireless card not establish a good connection until I used the command?

Tags: windows, tcp, ip, winsock

I am wondering exactly what the command `netsh winsock reset` does specifically and why/how it fixed my wireless issue I have been having for the last few months- on my Windows 10 computer.

I have read the wiki on winsock and have been doing research/found articles on sockets and it's functionality but I have not been able to find any solid explanation as to why/how this could have affected my wireless connections. I would try to connect and it would connect but claim to have "no internet access". It would connect but not load any webpages and such.

Can someone explain to me why/how using the commands `netsh int ip reset` and `netsh winsock reset` ultimately solved my issue with this? After running the commands the issue has been resolved. I am just wanting a deeper understanding.

Comment: netsh winsock reset will uninstall any network service providers (apart from those included in winsock.dll) present in a machine. Think bluetooth bridges, USB / network connections, malware installed providers... Now that the culprit is gone, I guess you´ll never know what was messing up your network stack.

Answer (score -2):

I have written complete article on windows [winsock reset](https://livefortech.net/netsh-winsock-reset/). You can read it and complete information.